# sending a location link as sms in background

Tags: java, android

i have created an app that shows user location in latitude and longitude . i now want this to take the latitude and longitude and send a Google maps link to other user through sms 
*the recievers phone number is set by the user
here is my working code

1 (AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java)

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
    } 
}
```

2(GPSTracker.java)

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Method for sending a sms:

```
 public void sendSms(String message, String number) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sentPI, null);

    }
```

Now In a message append a latitude and longitude with your string and in the number gave the number you want to send sms.

EDIT:

make your structure like this:

```
 class A {

        public void getLocation() {
            //your logic
            sendSms();
        }

        public void sendSms() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: in your getLocation() method when you get latitude and longitude. but it will send message every time you call that method.

Comment: @Nishal You can't add a method inside a method in Java.

Comment: @nishal just call a sendSms method. and put that method outside of getLocation() method.

Comment: could anyone could explain this to me in detail

Comment: see my Edit for Answer.